# MySQL will a composite index suffice a query that uses a JOIN?

Tags: mysql, indexing, primary-key, composite-primary-key

As I understand, composite indexes will accomplish what is needed in cases like this:

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE id_city = 3 AND id_type = 5
```

The **INDEX** would be (id_city, id_type). As long as all queries always filter those 2 combined fields, no other index would be ever necessary.

But what about queries where one of the fields is being used in the JOIN statement and the other one in the WHERE statement? Example:

```
SELECT user.name AS name
FROM user JOIN friend ON friends.id_str = user.id_str
WHERE friends.id_user = 3
```

Would the (id_user, id_str) **INDEX** be enough in the **friends** table? (btw, i'm not asking about the **user** table, that's of course another case).

EXPLAIN of current SELECT:
[image]

Comment: That index should be fine, but not for the reason you expect, because you have not accounted for the fact that `user JOIN friend` is exactly the same, logically, as `friend JOIN user`.  You have to remember the possibility that it will be planned and executed in the opposite order than what the query implies.  I would expect the optimizer to start with friends and then join users.  `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` on your query, and show the results, please.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot hi, i just added a screenshot of the EXPLAIN statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your initial query, yes, `(id_city, id_type)` *in either order* is optimal.  Tacking on `name` *last* would be slightly better (due to being "covering").

Moving on...

For that *specific* query, have these indexes:

```
friend:   (id_user, id_str)  -- in this order; "covering"
user:     (id_str, name)     -- in this order; "covering"
```

Here is what is going on:

1. The Optimizer sees `JOIN` and some stuff about one of the tables (`friends`) in the `WHERE`, so it decides to start with `friend`.
2. To handle the `WHERE`, it needs an index *starting* with what is in `WHERE`, namely `id_str`.
3. Since there is not much else needed from `friend`, let's put all the columns in the index, hence "covering".  `EXPLAIN` will indicate such by saying `Using index`.
4. Now, to get to the other table (`user`).  The `ON` clause needs `id_str`, so put it *first* in an index.
5. Again, let's play the covering game by adding on `name`.

I cover this stuff more generically [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) .

If your *real* query looks different *in any way*, then all bets are off.  That is, the indexes I suggest may *or may not* be beneficial.

If you want to discuss further, please provide

- `SHOW CREATE TABLE`
- The *real* queries.